# Arranging Grid items depending on other items' visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I have a Panel that shows Labels, TextBoxes, and ComboBoxes and the code behind sets the visibility to visible or collapsed depending upon the user's choice from a ComboBox outside of said Panel.  What would be the best way to eliminate the gaps in the Panel, and to get all of the items that are visible to the right side of the grid (decrease the column position if there are empty cells at the bottom of the previous column)? What type of Panel should I use? Should I split them into separate panels?

Edit:

Here is a poor Excel interpretation of what i would like to happen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAu35.jpg

I essentially want to make everything go to the top left corner

Comment: `and the code behind sets the visibility to visible or collapsed` - Do not use code behind. Create a proper ViewModel. WPF is not winforms. Learn MVVM.

Comment: @HighCore , I disagree. Not every WPF application needs to use MVVM. If the application is just a lightweight utility that won't need to be maintained frequently, than having event handlers in the code behind isn't necessarily a bad thing. As with all best practices and design patterns, they are rewarding only when the benefit up weights the added complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand your layout without some diagram or sketch, but I think you can stay with the Grid layout if you set the row height/column width to "auto". This will cause each grid row/column to be large just enough to present its own content.

You can also use other layout types such as StackPanel or DockPanel, they give you less control over the positioning of your controls, but provide comfortable automatic layout.

EDIT:

You can use a `WrapPanel` to get the expected results:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label/>
    <TextBox/>
    <ComboBox/>
</WrapPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, had to adjust the size to get it box shaped instead of a list of inputs, but works like a charm!